# How to identify videos from my Youtube channel by a category with YoutubeApi-V3 filtering tags?

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the Youtube API v3 for the first time, to receive all my videos from my youtube channel in my Java Web-application. But I like to categorize them by special categories.

What I do is, that I got my webpage and I like to display a categorized list by videos from my channel. I use a public key to identify my application.

The idea I have, is to set tags for the videos, query them and to identify the category by that special tag.

The question is, is it possible to query all the videos from my channel by a tag?
Something like I use a QueryTerm that filters by that tag and makes me receive the videos by that tag.

The code to receive the videos looks like that at the moment.

```
    // Create the youtube object
    YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException{}}).setApplicationName("MyApp").build();

    // Initialize the search
    YouTube.Search.List search = null;
    try
    {
        search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
    }
    catch(IOException e1)
    {
        throw new PipeletExecutionException("Failure during sending youtube search request");
    }

    // Set API-Key
    search.setKey(cfg_apiKey);
    search.setChannelId(cfg_channelId);
    // Set Request Query
    // search.setQ(queryTerm);

    // search.type("playlist"); oder  search.type("channel");
    search.setType("playlist");

    // Set Fields, filters onle the filds that are defined
    search.setFields("items(id/videoId,snippet(title,description,thumbnails))");

    // Call the API and consume the results
    SearchListResponse searchResponse = null;
   // List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();

    try
    {
        searchResponse = search.execute();
        System.out.println(searchResponse.toPrettyString());
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        throw new PipeletExecutionException("Failure during sending youtube search request");
    }

    dict.put(DN_YOUTUBE_LISTS, searchResponse);
```

Comment: If you have custom categories that you're setting up, playlists would certainly be the easiest way to go. If you're comfortable with YouTube's already existing guide categories, however (you select the category when uploading a video), you could use the "search" endpoint, pass in the channelId and the categoryId, and get back all the video details that way. It would only be one call per category that way instead of two with the other solution, but it may limit how you're dividing your videos.

Comment: I think using tags to identify the category of a video seems a good way to achieve this, because servicing the channel would be much easier than to create playlists for categories. Given that idea I have another question, is it possible to query all videos by a special tag ???

Comment: Using tags makes things a little bit difficult, because tags are only visible for the uploader. So it seems like I can not use them for my categories.

Comment: Correct; tags are for the channel manager's use, but they aren't exposed to the API for searching or listing videos. There are 3 options -- categories (which uploaders also assign but which are exposed to the API), playlists, or topic IDs ... the only problem with topic IDs is that YouTube automatically assigns those, so you can't use them to group videos per your own organization.